# How to use Read::take recursively to read a tree structures with a generic Read trait?

Tags: recursion, io, rust

When storing tree structures in binary files its fairly common to store a sequence of *chunks*, each containing:  `[type_id, size, ... ]` and optionally nested child chunks.

This allows readers to read in the tree, skipping types that aren't recognized since their size is known.

See: [Amiga IFF as an example of this](http://www.fileformat.info/format/iff/egff.htm).

When writing readers for this kind of data, its important to make sure each level of the recursion reads exactly the number of bytes defined by its chunk size.

Even using the `Seek` trait, while it allows skipping to the next chunk, it doesn't ensure nested functions aren't reading past their bounds.

So its useful that reading past the pre-defined chunk size will cause an EOF.

Is there a way to use [`Read::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.take) to get a part of the file sized to the chunk, then read from it in a recursive function?

---

In principle this should be possible, however I ran into a problem using take recursively, where I couldn't get generic types working:

```
error: reached the recursion limit while instantiating `decode_recursive::<&mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &[u8]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Is it possible to use `Read::take` in a function to recursively limit the range of data that can be read?

Note that using vector `Slice` would resolve this but I would like to use the `Read` trait.

---

Example code which encodes a small tree structure and tries to read it:

```
use ::std::io;

fn encode_recursive(data: &mut Vec<u8>, chunk_size: u8) {
    let data_len_init = data.len();
    let mut size = chunk_size;
    size -= 2;
    if size > 8 {
        data.push(2); // children
        data.push(size);
        let split = size / 2;
        encode_recursive(data, split);
        encode_recursive(data, size - split);
    } else {
        data.push(0); // no children
        data.push(size);
        for i in 0..size {
            data.push(i); // dummy leaf data
        }
    }
    debug_assert_eq!(data.len(), data_len_init + chunk_size as usize);
}

fn decode_recursive<R>(mut f: R, depth: usize) -> Result<(), io::Error>
    where R: io::Read,
{
    let mut chunk_data: [u8; 2] = [0; 2];
    io::Read::read_exact(&mut f, &mut chunk_data)?;
    let children = chunk_data[0];
    let chunk_size = chunk_data[1];

    let mut f_sub = io::Read::take(&mut f, chunk_size as u64);

    println!("{:indent$}Chunk: {} depth", "", chunk_data[0], indent=depth);
    if children != 0 {
        for _ in 0..children {
            decode_recursive(&mut f_sub, depth + 1)?;
        }
    } else {
        let mut chunk_leaf: [u8; 1] = [0; 1];
        for _ in 0..(chunk_size as usize) {
            io::Read::read_exact(&mut f_sub, &mut chunk_leaf)?;
            print!("{},", chunk_leaf[0]);
        }
        println!();
    }

    // read all remaining data in the case recursive functions finish early.
    io::copy(&mut f_sub, &mut io::sink())?;

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

    {
        let size_init = 255_u8;
        encode_recursive(&mut data, size_init);
    }

    decode_recursive(&*data, 0).unwrap();
}
```

See: [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ceff10d39dd4515dcad5a6d1880c7b72&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you'll have to use trait objects instead of generics.

The problem is that in your code, each recursive call sets `R` to `&mut std::io::Take<&mut R>`. That's not the same `R` as the original call, so the compiler is forced to instantiate another instance of `decode_recursive`. But this happens indefinitely because the new `R` is derived from the old `R`!

Concretely:

- the first call (in `main`) instantiates `decode_recursive<&[u8]>`
- which invokes `decode_recursive<&mut std::io::Take<&mut &[u8]>>`
- which invokes `decode_recursive<&mut std::io::Take<&mut &mut std::io::Take<&mut &[u8]>>>`
- etc.

The compiler cannot figure out when this recursion will stop!

Therefore, as mentioned above, the solution is to use trait objects instead. Since the methods on `Read` that read data need a mutable reference, that's what your function will have to receive.

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;

fn decode_recursive(f: &mut Read, depth: usize) -> Result<(), io::Error>
{
    let mut chunk_data: [u8; 2] = [0; 2];
    f.read_exact(&mut chunk_data)?;
    let children = chunk_data[0];
    let chunk_size = chunk_data[1];

    let mut f_sub = f.take(chunk_size as u64);

    println!("{:indent$}Chunk: {} depth", "", chunk_data[0], indent=depth);
    if children != 0 {
        for _ in 0..children {
            decode_recursive(&mut f_sub, depth + 1)?;
        }
    } else {
        let mut chunk_leaf: [u8; 1] = [0; 1];
        for i in 0..(chunk_size as usize) {
            f_sub.read_exact(&mut chunk_leaf)?;
            print!("{},", i);
        }
        println!();
    }

    // read all remaining data in the case recursive functions finish early.
    io::copy(&mut f_sub, &mut io::sink())?;

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

    {
        let size_init = 255_u8;
        encode_recursive(&mut data, size_init);
    }

    decode_recursive(&mut &*data, 0).unwrap();
}
```

Note that this uses the implementation `impl<'a, R: Read + ?Sized> Read for &'a mut R` provided by the standard library when invoking `take`. `Read` is an object-safe trait, so `Read` (the type) implements `Read` (the trait) (this implementation is provided by the compiler), and therefore thanks to the above `impl` in the standard library, `&mut Read` also implements `Read`. This results in `f_sub` having type `std::io::Take<&mut std::io::Read>`.

Comment: Attempted to implement this, but still get errrors: see: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=774da2d80fc57b6faacd92697ffa81be&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: You're still using generics there, so you haven't solved the problem. You could possibly use [`Take::into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Take.html#method.into_inner) to feel off a layer of `Take` before doing a recursive call, but then either the function would have to require a `Take<R>` argument (even for the initial call), or you'd have to use specialization to be able to use `into_inner`. As much as I prefer generics to trait objects, this is a situation where I would concede that trait objects are the right approach.

Comment: I found it a bit confusing since the code snippet you posted isn't using `Take::into_inner`, is it supposed to be a working code example?

Comment: The code in my answer compiles (if you add `encode_recursive`, which I omitted because I didn't change it). Note that each recursive call will still wrap the `&mut Read` in a `Take` (it works because `&mut Read` implements `Read`; I've added that info in my answer). If it doesn't have the correct behavior though, I don't claim any responsibility; it's still your code after all. :)

Comment: This is what I get attempting to use your code example as-is: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6e8873f976af20ab56842adfc30b4ac9&version=stable&backtrace=0 - Realize I need to make sure what I have works properly, but its still hitting basic type errors.

Comment: Oh, that's because you didn't add `use std::io::Read;`, so `Read`'s methods are not in scope. Took me a few minutes to figure it out when I originally wrote my answer. :) Which makes me wonder, why didn't you use method call syntax on `Read`'s methods in your original code?

Comment: Method call syntax consumes the argument, IIRC. (moving ownership)

Answer (score 0):

Posting a working example based on @francis-gagné's suggetions and @aatch's help.

Even though its possible the answer should have been obvious, I couldn't figure out how to apply francis's suggestions without some help, and having a working code example in the answer is generally useful:

Note that the reason I couldn't get my original question working was using generic `Read` trait.

So changing:

```
fn decode_recursive<R>(mut f: R, depth: usize) -> Result<(), io::Error>
    where R: io::Read,
{ ... }
```

To:

```
fn decode_recursive(f: &mut io::Read, depth: usize) -> Result<(), io::Error> { ... }
```

This fixes the root cause of the problem I was running into.

Full working code example:

```
use ::std::io;

fn encode_recursive(data: &mut Vec<u8>, chunk_size: u8) {
    let data_len_init = data.len();
    let mut size = chunk_size;
    size -= 2;
    if size > 8 {
        data.push(2); // children
        data.push(size);
        let split = size / 2;
        encode_recursive(data, split);
        encode_recursive(data, size - split);
    } else {
        data.push(0); // no children
        data.push(size);
        for i in 0..size {
            data.push(i); // dummy leaf data
        }
    }
    debug_assert_eq!(data.len(), data_len_init + chunk_size as usize);
}

fn decode_recursive(f: &mut io::Read, depth: usize) -> Result<(), io::Error>
{
    let mut chunk_data: [u8; 2] = [0; 2];
    io::Read::read_exact(f, &mut chunk_data)?;
    let children = chunk_data[0];
    let chunk_size = chunk_data[1];

    let mut f_sub = io::Read::take(f, chunk_size as u64);

    println!("{:indent$}Chunk: {} depth", "", chunk_data[0], indent=depth);
    if children != 0 {
        for _ in 0..children {
            decode_recursive(&mut f_sub, depth + 1)?;
        }
    } else {
        let mut chunk_leaf: [u8; 1] = [0; 1];
        for _ in 0..(chunk_size as usize) {
            io::Read::read_exact(&mut f_sub, &mut chunk_leaf)?;
            print!("{},", chunk_leaf[0]);
        }
        println!();
    }

    // read all remaining data in the case recursive functions finish early.
    io::copy(&mut f_sub, &mut io::sink())?;

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

    {
        let size_init = 255_u8;
        encode_recursive(&mut data, size_init);
    }

    decode_recursive(&mut &*data, 0).unwrap();
}
```